# Compile in command line java desktop app written in NetBeans with netbeans gui editor?

Tags: java, netbeans, command-line, compilation

I made my project in Netbeans but my professor said it must be able to compile it with command line. So tried everything i still get errors like : org.jdesktop.application package does not exist?

Please help me how to feed the line in the command prompt.

Comment: In distinction to the other answers, I would clarify with the professor if non-J2SE classes are permitted in the solution.  I suspect not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [app-framework.jar](http://findjar.com/jar/net/java/dev/appframework/appframework/1.03/appframework-1.03.jar.html) in your classpath, which is there in classpath if you run it from NB.

Comment: I added it. But I still get error. I added javac -cp /lib/app-framework-1.0.3.jar ATMMain.java

But I still get errors. :S

Comment: try ./lib/app-framework-1.0.3.jar (notice the dot in the beginning)

Comment: Check the path. it seems wrong, try giving full path like./home/username/../appframework.jar

Comment: `ATM\ATM\dist>java -cp c:\appframework-1.03.jar -jar ATM.jar`  Note I am using win machine for now and app-framework resides in `c:\ `currently for me , *It works for me*

Answer (score 1):

Use `-classpath` key of javac to include the appropriate jar.

```
C:\...\ATM\ATM\src\atm>javac
ATMApp.java ATMView.java CheckIDandPIN.java AccountDetailsServices.java -cp appf
ramework-1.03.jar
```

This works if the appframework.jar is located in one folder with ATMApp.java

```
C:\...\ATM\ATM\src>java -classpath .;appframework-1.03.jar atm.ATMApp
```

This launches your application if you copy the jar to src folder.

Comment: It compiles it. Hahaha. Thank you. But When I run java ATMApp.class or without .class it gives exception that class is not found. Gosh!

Comment: because you should run it from ATM\src.

Comment: But the class files are now in the same folder with the source files in \src

Comment: Java searches for the class file using the folder structure which reflects the package structure. learn a bit more java please.

Comment: see update. And give at least one upvote to org.life.java as he really helps you.

Comment: THANK YOU TO ALL OF YOU! ESPECIALLY TO VLADIMIR! THANK YOU AGAIN!

Answer (score 0):

sounds like a misunderstanding.  By default, Netbeans uses ant to build projects.  Ant ***is*** a CLI build tool.  So, most any Netbeans project will easily compile and build as a JAR from the CLI.  Simply run `ant -p build.xml` from in the project directory.  You should see options to build.  As far as I can recall, `ant jar` will build and distribute most any SE project out of the box.

That's building from the CLI.

Probably the instructions were (back in 2010) to use `javac` directly.

As Jigar said, you have a classpath problem.  Your classpath problem is unrelated to building the JAR from the Netbeans GUI or from the CLI.